# Is it possible to plot a barchart with upper and lower limits of the bins with Pandas,seaborn or Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I will like to know how I can go about plotting a barchart with upper and lower limits of the bins represented by the values in the `age_classes` column of the dataframe shown below with `pandas`, `seaborn` or `matplotlib`. A sample of the dataframe looks like this:

```
age_classes total_cases male_cases  female_cases
0   0-9     693     381     307
1   10-19   931     475     454
2   20-29   4530    1919    2531
3   30-39   7466    3505    3885
4   40-49   13701   6480    7130
5   50-59   20975   11149   9706
6   60-69   18089   11761   6254
7   70-79   19238   12281   6868
8   80-89   16252   8553    7644
9   >90     4356    1374    2973
10  Unknown 168     84      81
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a chart like this:

[image]

then you can make it with `sns.barplot` setting `age_classes` as `x` and one columns (in my case `total_cases`) as `y`, like in this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sns.barplot(ax = ax,
            data = df,
            x = 'age_classes',
            y = 'total_cases')

plt.show()
```